# php cookie, how do I update the value?

Tags: php, cookies

I have some simple PHP code:

```
setcookie('fontSize',28, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
```

This works great, and the cookie is set, the value of 28 can be retrieved, etc.  But if I change the value from 28 to, say, 48, save the file, and refresh the page, the value doesn't update to 48, but stays 28.

I suppose I could put a line of code to delete the cookie, and then set it again with the setcookie() function, but that seems like a strange way to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: weird setcookie() function should update the cookie value by name.

Comment: You can't *update* a cookie per se, only set them. So I'd simply use `setcookie()` whenever I want to overwrite an existing cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, in PHP, there is no function to truly update a cookie. 
What I generally use to change the value of a cookie is the `setcookie()` function.

In your case, you just want to use `setCookie('fontSize', 48, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/')` to overwrite the cookie named `fontSize` to one with that new value. Ensure you use the `'/'` parameter in the `setcookie(...)` function to ensure you aren't creating **another** cookie with that same name but in a different directory.
The problem with this solution however is that you cannot keep your previous expiration date and have to assign it with a new expiration date.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  In fact, the problem was that I needed to refresh my page twice, which I knew but hadn't realized.

Comment: Ah, ok! I thought that might be the case and was in the midst of editing in about refreshing. Glad you got it! :)

Answer (score 3):

I needed to refresh the page twice after changing the value.  Details, details, details...